# How can I import a .txt file into a Database?

Tags: mysql, database, file

I have a .txt file, this file is saving data of further excel tables. The text file has the data from each column separated by a comma, it has the following format:

"GTCEN8B","GU_Bantrab_Diagonal_6_(1754)","0","WG1754B","PCS1900","704","01","258","17542","0","7","Normal_cell","Normal_cell","","","","","OFF","","3","5","4","6","1","4","1","NO","NO","NO","4294967295","-","UNLOCK","ACTIVATED","Claro"
"GTCEN8B","GU_Bantrab_Diagonal_6_(1754)","2","WG1754D","GSM900","704","01","258","17544","5","5","Normal_cell","Normal_cell","","","","","OFF","","3","5","4","6","1","4","1","NO","NO","NO","4294967295","-","UNLOCK","ACTIVATED","Claro"

What I want to do is to introduce the text file into a Database, separating each data by columns in order to arrange the information in a table. 
But I don't know how to do that, I got only basic knowledge of MySQL

I'd very grateful if you can help me.

Comment: You will first need to use a CREATE TABLE, and then a LOAD DATA to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple load in file option like below

`load data infile 'C:/filepath/files/data.csv'
into  table1
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
(C1,c2,...)`

Advice- you should have done some googling before posting this question. You must have got many solutions with complete working example that you should have translated into your solution.